# How to use a certificate for encryption in java se

Tags: java, encryption, certificate

I've to code an app in java that let the user write a text and use a certificate to encrypt this string and show it (encrypted) in a textfield.
I coded the graphical interface but i've searched for how to use certificate to encrypt/decrypt a variable in java and i didn't find something for my case !
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please post what you have done till now. Also clarify your question as how you wish to use SSL Certificate in offline application?

Comment: Certificate contains public key, extract that public key and encrypt the text with that public key.

Comment: @Blip i've just coded an interface with netbeans ( 2 textfields one for input plaintext and another will be used to show the encrypted text).
For ssl certificate it will be used in offline app, i want to import my certificate ceated by me, in app and use it for encryption/decryption.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with SSL, unless that's the only thing you're really asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your certificate can be exported as a file (eg.: "mycert.cer"). Then use the API provided by JCA (Java Cryptography Architecture) to manipulate it.

For instance, to read the certificate, you could use

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("mycert.cer");
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509");
X509Certificate crt = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(fis);
```

From the public key of `X509Certificate` object, you could encrypt your text. Everything that you need is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/Certificate.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html).